# How to get data sorted with relation using TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to get user data with relation sorted but with this code it just sort the user but I want to sort data that have relation with user I'm  using eager,  could any one help me ?

```
getUerWithId(pramas: string): Observable<userEntity[]> {
        return from(this.userRepository.find({
            where: [
                { id: pramas }
            ],
            order:{
                 id:'DESC'
            }
        }))
    }
```

Comment: could you specify which relations you wanna sort? Maybe you just bring the "User" as a relation and select from your relation table.

Comment: the user entity  has relation with notification entity ,normally when I get user data  I get it with notification data because I am using eager relation,  I  want to sort notification

Comment: With eager relation, I don't know any solution, but you can try as the example posted.

Comment: If there are not too many results, you can sort the results with "array.sort()" after you get the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the repository, I don't know if it is possible, but you can try with query builder to get ordered relations. Follow example bellow:

```
this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder()
      .innerJoinAndSelect("User.notification", "Notification") 
      .orderBy({'Notification.createdAt': 'DESC'})
      .where("User.id = :id", {
        id: Number(id),
      })
      .getOne();
```

Remember to put the right relationship for your entity, and right names for your properties.

Comment: yes , it works thanks